# How to get Colormap from Tif file

Tags: c#

My tif file is indexed 8 bpp and was saved with a colormap.

Is there any way to recover that colormap from the file in C#?

At default, picturebox automatically displays the colormap like this as far left and right represent 0 and 255.

[image]

I searched for it all over internet in vain.

If there is no way to do this, how can somebody decide a color in a pixel of indexed 8 bpp image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to edit the color map, you can simply modify the image's palette:

```
System.Drawing.Image image = Image.FromFile(@"Q:\my_image.tif");
System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorPalette palette = image.Palette;
//...palette.Entries is simply an array of System.Drawing.Color, modify to suit

//crucial step - palette was retrieved as a copy, so
//it is necessary to store the copy back to the image
image.Palette = palette;
```

If you save the image back out as a tiff, the modified palette goes with it.